# How to change the type with GADTs in Haskell

Tags: haskell, gadt

Following the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26084087/8142021
I used the following haskell code to define a Modal Logic with GADTs.

```hs
data Plain
data Mod
data Formula t where
   Prop :: {propName :: String} -> Formula t
   Neg  :: Formula t -> Formula t
   Conj :: Formula t -> Formula t -> Formula t
   Disj :: Formula t -> Formula t -> Formula t
   Impl :: Formula t -> Formula t -> Formula t
   BiImpl :: Formula t -> Formula t -> Formula t
   MyModality :: Formula Mod -> Formula Mod 

type PlainFormula = Formula Plain
type ModalFormula = Formula Mod
```

Is there a way to change the type of a PlainFormula to a ModalFormula? Since PlainFormula is a subset of Modal Formula, I tried to define the following injection but it did not work.

```hs
toModal :: PlainFormula -> ModalFormula
toModal f = f
```

Comment: I wish there were a way to perform this in O(1). AFAIK, the only way is to recurse over all the formula and reconstruct it, in O(N).

Comment: @chi I could define toModal using recursion as you said. I will use that for now. Thanks.

Comment: In this case, you could instead define `PlainFormula = forall t. PlainFormula t` which would give you this conversion for free.  Maybe this approach could be generalized with some type classes instead of concrete types, so you would have `MyModality :: Modal t => Formula t -> Formula t`, and `type ModalFormula = forall t. Modal t => Formula t`.  Might not be as fun to work with in practice as one would hope, though

Comment: PlainFormula may be a subset of ModalFormula but your data type doesn't allow this, i.e. you cannot `Conj` a modal formula and a plain formula.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. So, if I want to `Conj` a modal formula `f` and a plain formula `g`, I must convert `g` into a modal formula. That's what I tried to achieve. I could do it but at the cost of recursion.

Comment: @luqui I need to read more about type classes to understand your approach. Thanks.

Comment: I would do something like this https://pastebin.pl/view/2b47d737 so you don't need to convert and you can have an hierarchy of different modalities.