# How should I specify the type in a instance statement when there is a type class restriction?

Tags: haskell

I was trying to define a very simple data structure that is suppose to add an `Infinity` element to any type under `Num`. I also put it under a defined class `NumContainer`, which has a method `fromNum` that construct a `NumWithInf` using a regular `Num`. The code is really straight forward.

```
data NumWithInf a = Infinity | Finite a deriving Show

class NumContainer k where
    fromNum :: Num a => a -> k

instance Num a => NumContainer (NumWithInf a) where
    fromNum x = Finite x
```

However when I ran it, GHCI gave me the following error:

```
hw.hs:7:24:
    Could not deduce (a ~ a1)
    from the context (Num a)
      bound by the instance declaration at hw.hs:6:10-45
    or from (Num a1)
      bound by the type signature for
                 fromNum :: Num a1 => a1 -> NumWithInf a
      at hw.hs:7:5-24
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the instance declaration at hw.hs:6:10
      `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
           the type signature for fromNum :: Num a1 => a1 -> NumWithInf a
           at hw.hs:7:5
    In the first argument of `Finite', namely `x'
    In the expression: Finite x
    In an equation for `fromNum': fromNum x = Finite x
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I understand that it says the `x` in `Finite x` doesn't necessarily have the same type as `a` in the signature `fromNum :: Num a => a -> k`. How should I specify this?

Comment: Unsolicited design suggestion: see how far you can get without the class, I doubt you actually need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution (i.e. one that does not resort to fancy type system trickery) is making your class work with  types of kind `* -> *` rather than `*`. In practice, that just means you define it as:

```
class NumContainer k where
    fromNum :: Num a => a -> k a -- Result type parametrised on `a`
```

The instance then becomes:

```
instance NumContainer NumWithInf where
    fromNum x = Finite x
```

Note that there is no place to put a `Num` constraint in the instance. That would be unnecessary anyway - the constraint in the type of `fromNum` is good enough already.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to stop users from constructing `Finite 'a'`? I think for some reason Haskell doesn't let programmers restrict arguments of constructors.

Comment: @trVoldemort The easiest way to stop users from constructing arbitrary `Finite a` is not exporting the `Finite` constructor from the module where you define it. For a much fancier way that probably is overkill for what you are doing, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7438716/2751851). (Curio: the question there was about the `DatatypeContexts` extension. It allowed writing `data Num a => NumWithInf a`; however, it was deprecated due to uselessness.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are trying to define `fromNum` from ANY `Num` to ANY other `Num` which is not possible. You would like something like

```
fromNum x = Finite (toNum x)
```

where `toNum` convert `x` to the correct `Num`. This is not possible in the general case. However, your *container* is in fact an applicative functor and your function `fromNum` (with a narrower signature `a -> k a`) is just `pure`.

Also you can define easily an `Num` instance for `NumContainer` and then you can implement `fromInteger` as

```
frommInteger a = Finite (fromInteger a)
```

The conversion is now possible because you are not starting from an arbitrary `Num` but from an `Integer`.

Please also not, that at the moment without just one `Infinite` your type is isomorph to `Maybe`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a typeclass ? A typeclass is usually needed to overload a function depending on the type. So unless you are planning to have different containers  you probably don't need a typeclass and could just do

```
 fromNum :: Num a => a -> NumWithInf a
 fromNum = Finite
```

However, your question "How should I specify the type in a instance statement when there is a type class restriction?" you can do it using `MultiParamTypeClasse` and pass `a` as a parameter of your typeclass.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

data NumWithInf a = Infinity | Finite a deriving Show

class NumContainer a k  where
       fromNum :: Num a => a -> k

instance Num a => NumContainer a (NumWithInf a) where
       fromNum x = Finite  x
```