# Haskell: How to use type class with generic datatype?

Tags: haskell, generics, typeclass

Suppose that I have defined a list like this:

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

Now I want to make sure a `List` is only instantiated with a generic type which conforms to a specific type class (e.g. `Ord`). How can I do this?

I know it is possible to define type class constraint on a generic function which is going to work with `List` instances but is there a way to define such a constraint on the data type itself?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438600/datatypecontexts-deprecated-in-latest-ghc-why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A GADT can capture a dictionary for a constraint in a constructor.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Sortable a where
    Sortable :: Ord a => [a] -> Sortable a
--     ^          ^
--  constructor   |
--                |
--  captures an Ord dictionary
```

The dictionary is reintroduced when you pattern match on the constructor

```
sortSortable :: Sortable a -> Sortable a
sortSortable (Sortable xs) = Sortable (sort xs)
--               ^                     ^
-- match constructor                   |
--                                     |
-- reintroduces `Ord a` dictionary so it can be used in sort
```

`Sortable a` can be constructed when `a` has an `Ord a` instance

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

deriving instance Show a => Show (Sortable a)

main = print . sortSortable $ Sortable "Hello, world!"
```

But not when it doesn't

```
data Z = Z
  deriving (Show)

main = print . sortSortable $ Sortable [Z]
```

This results in an error because `Sortable` can't capture an `Ord Z` dictionary, because one doesn't exist.

```
No instance for (Ord Z) arising from a use of ‘Sortable’
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘Sortable [Z]’
In the expression: print . sortSortable $ Sortable [Z]
In an equation for ‘main’:
    main = print . sortSortable $ Sortable [Z]
```