# aeson ToJSON instances for polymorphic type

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

How to write a aeson ToJSON instances by hand for a polymorphic type like:

```hs
data Show a => Translatable a = Translatable (Map.Map String a)
    deriving (Show, Eq, Typeable)
```

I would like to encode a

```hs
Translatable $ Map.fromList [("key", "value"), ("key2", "value2")]
```

to a json object like
`{ "key", "value", "key2", "value2" }`

What I tried so far is this:

```hs
import qualified Data.Aeson as A
import Data.Data (Typeable)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

data Show a => Translatable a = Translatable (Map.Map String a)
    deriving (Show, Eq, Typeable)

instance Show a => A.ToJSON (Translatable a) where
    toEncoding xs = A.object $ map (.=) (Map.toList xs)
```

Error

```
 Couldn't match type ‘A.Value’
 with ‘Data.Aeson.Encoding.Internal.Encoding' A.Value’
      Expected type: A.Encoding
        Actual type: A.Value
```

The aeson documentation showes:
`type Encoding = Encoding' Value`

But A.Encoding' is not in scope

```
Not in scope: data constructor ‘A.Encoding'’
```

what am I doing wrong?

## EDIT:

I changed my Translatable to a type

```hs
type Translatable a = Map.Map String a
```

And now it works without adding Translatable as instance to ToJSON

But the initial question is still the question.

Comment: Why are you using broken and deprecated `DatatypeContexts`?

Comment: Also, are you just mixing up `toJSON` and `toEncoding`?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica
Oh it's deprecated?! Thanks for this information.

Comment: here I can read what you mean: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438600/datatypecontexts-deprecated-in-latest-ghc-why
But what i don't understand is that I am using ghc version 8.6.5 ... I don't get a warning or error when compiling my code.
@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the `toJSON` and `toEncoding` functions up. Just implement the `toJSON` function of your `ToJSON` instance. I imported `Data.Aeson` unqualified, to have less of a struggle with the operators.

```
import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.Text as T

--- etc.

instance Show a => ToJSON (Translatable a) where
    toJSON (Translatable myMap) = toJSON
        [ object [ T.pack key .= show val ] | (key, val) <- Map.toList myMap ]
```

We use the `toJSON` function on a list of json objects to create a json array. `T.pack key` is needed, since your map keys are `String`s, but `.=` needs a `Text`.