# Restricting a type variable to a class type in a data declaration in Haskell

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

I want to declare a data type that is constructed from a list of comparable elements. This is because I wrote a function that only works correctly if its input lists are sorted, and I wanted a way to get the compiler to stop its being accidentally used on unsorted lists. (I don't think there's any way to stop a user lying, but I at least wanted them to declare the lists as sorted).

It doesn't make sense (to me) to have a sorted list unless the elements of the list are in Ord, and I wanted to try to get the compiler to enforce at least this much.

```
data WrappedList a = WrappedList [a]

data SortedList (Ord a) => a = SortedList [a]
```

SortedList is one of my failed attempts, whilst WrappedList does actually compile. I can't find any examples of this, so maybe I've missed the point completely?

(N.B. I've just starting learning Haskell and this is a toy problem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you could create your `SortedList` type, the function you want to write will most likely have a type that looks a bit like:

```
myFunc :: Ord a => SortedList a -> ...
```

If `myFunc` doesn't have the `Ord` constraint then it won't be able to use comparison functions (which would mean it's completely unable to observe whether the list is sorted or not; that doesn't make the fact that it's sorted *completely* useless, but certainly you would lose a large part of the utility of knowing it was already sorted).

That means that if someone wants to call `myFunc` with a type that *doesn't* have an `Ord` constraint, the compiler is going to call them on it anyway. So stopping them from constructing the `SortedList a` if they can't prove `Ord a` doesn't actually catch any additional errors. So simply adding an `Ord a` constraint to `SortedList` itself is probably not something you should put a lot of effort into; it actually buys you very little. A simple type like this:

```
data SortedList a = SortedList [a]

-- Actually it could be a newtype, which is a bit more efficient; but don't worry
-- about it if you don't know what that is yet
newtype SortedList a = SortedList [a]
```

works fine to create the situation where it's hard to accidentally call your function on an unsorted list (the caller would have to deliberately lie to you, or at least be negligent about assuming a list from elsewhere was sorted), and the `Ord` constraints on functions that do anything interesting with the order in a `SortedList` will catch anyone using your functions with lists that actually can't be sorted (by a canonical order) because their element type doesn't even have such an order.

Haskell in fact *used* to have [a feature for doing exactly what you're after](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/exts/datatype_contexts.html), but after the experience of having it the expert and community consensus was that it is better not to have the feature at all. It has been deprecated, is no longer available by default in newer GHC versions, and will be removed entirely at some point. So since you are learning Haskell, I recommend you simply never learn how to use this feature. Learning to solve problems without it is a useful skill that will carry over into future Haskell; learning to rely on it is a dead end.

---

If you really want the `Ord a` check to be made at the point where the `SortedList` wrapper is constructed the way to do that in more modern Haskell is to use the `GADTs` language extension. This is however a more advanced Haskell feature, so probably not something you should try to tackle when you're still learning the ropes.

But for completeness, it would allow you to write a type like this:

```
data SortedList a where
  SortedList :: Ord a => [a] -> SortedList a
```

This means that when the `SortedList` constructor is applied the compiler will not just check `Ord a`, it will actually *store* the `Ord` instance inside the `SortedList` value. Functions that *use* a `SortedList` then don't actually need an `Ord` constraint, because they get access to the stored instance when pattern matching on the `SortedList`.

Be careful about using this technique everywhere though; it can cause significant performance issues. If you use many values with a stored instance you'll potentially use a lot of memory storing references to the same instance (and time dereferencing all those references). But even worse this technique defeats a lot of optimisations the compiler can usually make. The compiler can often inline and specialise functions with typeclass constraints so that they end up calling statically-known typeclass methods, which can be much faster than calling them through a runtime dictionary. When *you're* managing the dictionary passing (by having them stored in GADTs) instead of the compiler, it can become much harder for the compiler to make these optimisations.

If you dig further into GADTs you'll also find that they let you "hide" type parameters, and *that* opens a large can of worms that you need a very firm grasp on Haskell's type system and syntax to keep hold of. Or at least the error messages you're likely to get when something goes wrong are very confusing to a novice, which makes them hard to correct.

GADTs are a really powerful feature that enables ways of structuring your code that simply couldn't be done with vanilla Haskell data types. My personal rubrik is to save them for cases like that, and not use them merely to catch an error a bit earlier that the compiler would have caught anyway. That's a cost-benefit tradeoff you'll have to make for yourself. But certainly GADTs are well worth learning and mastering at some point in your Haskell journey!

---

If you want to go further and *actually* have a data type that the compiler enforces to be a sorted list, then there in fact are ways to do that. The most straightforward way doesn't even need `GADTs`! The trick is to use the module system. (If you're not already comfortable with writing multi-module programs, then probably save this for later; your instinct to make the compiler enforce your invariants is very good Haskell, but you won't be able to do everything that Haskell is capable of while you're just getting started)

In a *separate* module from your other code (i.e. in a file `SortedList.hs`), write something like this:

```
module SortedList
  ( SortedList   -- note this just exports the *type* name, not the constructor
  , fromUnsorted
  , empty
  , elements
  , sortedInsert
  , unsafeFromSorted
  )
where

import Data.List (sort, insert)

newtype SortedList a = SL [a]

fromUnsorted :: Ord a => [a] -> SortedList a
fromUnsorted = SL . sort

empty :: SortedList a
empty = SL []

elements :: SortedList a -> [a]
elements (SL xs) = xs

sortedInsert :: Ord a => a -> SortedList a -> SortedList a
sortedInsert x (SL xs) = SL $ insert x xs

-- Optionally include a function like this to allow a programmer to declare
-- that a list is *already* sorted. Having an option like this is equivalent
-- to exporting the constructor, so it loses the guarantee that the list is
-- *always* sorted. But there are often ways to build a list that is sorted by
-- construction (e.g. [1..100]), so having to call `sort` on them is a
-- performance hit. Take your pick between performance and safety.
unsafeFromSorted :: [a] -> SortedList a
unsafeFromSorted = SL
```

The key thing is that we haven't exported the constructor `SL` (which I've named differently from the `SortedList` only to avoid confusion when I'm talking about them). Nobody outside this module can apply `SL` to a random unsorted list. They would have to use the `fromUnsorted` function which is going to sort the list. Alternatively if they already have a `SortedList` they can use `sortedInsert` to add a new element, but that maintains the property that the output list is sorted if the input was. (Or they can use `empty`, since an empty list is obviously always sorted)

If those are the *only* ways that other parts of the program can get access to a `SortedList`, then you always know that such a list is sorted. The `elements` function extracts the elements as a raw list (needed since the constructor isn't available so nobody can pattern match to get them); this throws away guarantee but allows full access to ordinary list functions.

The `sortedInsert` function isn't strictly *necessary*; you could always use `fromUnsorted . insert x . elements` to do the same thing. But that is much less efficient, since it requires re-checking that the list is sorted to convert it back to a `SortedList` at the end, and we know that [`insert`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html#v:insert) is always going to produce a sorted result if the input is sorted. So including an analogue of `insert` makes it easier and more efficient to work with `SortedList`s. Similarly you could think of other list operations that can be done (more efficiently) in a way that maintains the sorted invariant and include those. The more of this you do, the less need there is for something like `unsafeFromSorted`, as people will be able to work with `SortedList`s directly instead of working with ordinary lists and then converting them at the end.

Comment: As far as I can tell, GHC never fully implemented `DatatypeContexts` as it was meant to work, and as it happened, no one has had both the will and the time to revisit the design and finish it. It did turn out to be more subtle than expected, for sure. But I dunno if that counts as a consensus that the feature itself was a mistake—in fact I’d still be glad to see it come together some day, or some suitable replacement anyway.

Comment: @JonPurdy I was under the impression that the way `DatatypeContexts` worked in GHC was precisely what was specified in the Haskell report; am I wrong? If not, one can argue the idea was only a part of a hypothetical future design, but the design that *did* exist was **in the language spec**, not some half-baked idea of the GHC devs, and it was fully implemented (also in other Haskell implementations). That feature, as it existed in the spec, is pretty widely viewed to be a mistake.

Comment: @Ben Thank you very much for this very in-depth answer. This has really clarified the issue for me and I've implemented the middle-ground solution using the GADTs. This was probably overkill for a function that gets used exactly once in my code, but it was quite instructive. I think the module stuff is a little beyond me at the moment, but I'll come back to it.

Comment: @Ben: That’s right, it’s in Haskell 98 §4.2.1, and even Haskell 1.0 (1990). By ca. 1993 it was clear that it was inconsistent with user expectations, _and_ inconsistent between compilers. The Haskell 98 committee discussed it at length ca. 1997–2000. “However,” Olaf Chitil wrote in August 2000, “in the end it was left as unsatisfactory as it is, because [it] would require considerable changes of Haskell. John Hughes wrote a proposal for a better semantics […]: _Restricted Datatypes in Haskell_. From that paper you will see that the semantics you would like to have is not that easy to obtain.”

Comment: @JonPurdy I was barely starting to learn Haskell in 2000, so I missed all of that discussion; I do remember thinking data contexts would be really handy and gradually realising they were effectively just an annoying form of documentation. I'm actually not sure what we'd want `DatatypeContexts` to do if it isn't GADT-like instance encapsulation, which we have now. Unless it's *invisibly* adding the constraint to all functions mentioning the type, which I don't think I want... So maybe it's just the Blub paradox biting me, but I don't think there's anything in that space I wish I had but don't.

Comment: @thecloisterbell Glad it was useful! Modules are extremely simple really, but if you're going beyond single-file programs you'll most likely also need to learn how to set up proper packages with .cabal files, and *that*'s a bit of learning. I sortof didn't really expect you to run with the GADT idea, so I've added a little bit to the answer about the downsides of overuse. But good on you for experimenting with something new!

Answer (score 3):

You can declare it with [DataTypeContexts](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/exts/datatype_contexts.html) extension, but as described in the document, it's considered a misfeature and you're discouraged to use it.

You can find why it's considered a misfeature at [DatatypeContexts Deprecated in Latest GHC: Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438600/datatypecontexts-deprecated-in-latest-ghc-why).

```
data Ord a => SortedList = SortedList [a]
```

Instead of adding constraints to your data type, you can add constraints to functions that actually need the constraints. For example, you can add `Ord a =>` to a function to build `SortedList` or a function to find an element using binary search.

```
buildSortedList :: Ord a => [a] -> SortedList [a]
buildSortedList = ...
```